# debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed. Why?

Tags: docker

I am having this error while making docker image.
How to solve this
Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 software-properties-common all 0.96.20.10 [9504 B]
debconf: delaying package configuration, **since apt-utils is not installed**
Fetched 14.4 MB in 8s (1686 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libssl1.0.0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 4785 files and directories currently installed.)